# Finding permutation polynomials in finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that a polynomial is a permutation polynomial when for every value of x in say GF(q) maps also to GF(Q) in a bijection.

For instance: $g(x)=x^3+1 \in GF(11)$

How would I find such a polynomial? Is there a formula?

For example I am asked to find all permutation polynomials of GF(2), how might I go about doing it?

Comment: Google Hermite's Criterion. This gives two necessary and sufficient conditions for a polynomial on a finite field to be a permutation polynomial. Yet I don't think there's a formula...

Comment: @DonAntonio, interesting, then would a general form of polynomials that I can use to consider as PP from a field be: $A_nx^n+A_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+A_{1}x+A_0$ where $A_n \in GF(q)$ but n could be anything right so there is an infinite number of polynomials with GF(q) coefficients to consider right?

Comment: Apparently so, indeed.

Comment: Am I correct that a permutation polynomial for GF(2) only has to satisfy $p(0)\ne p(1)$?